# Why does my Tensorflow based Gradient Descent breaks mid run?

Tags: tensorflow

I am learning Tensorflow and am trying to make a shallow neural network on the MNIST dataset.

The algorithm seems to be working until it reaches a certain point where it completely breaks. It goes back to randomly predicting the labels and does not improve.

Thank you for your help.

Code :

```py
# MNIST Data

[train_data, cv_data, test_data] = loadMnistData()
[x_train, y_train] = train_data
[x_cv, y_cv] = cv_data
[x_test, y_test] = test_data
[m,n] = np.shape(x_train)
[m,o] = np.shape(y_train)

# Hyperparameters

ALPHA = 0.5
BATCH_SIZE = 10
ITERATIONS = 30

# Build

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784]) 
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 30], stddev=.01))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([30]))

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([30, 10], stddev=.01))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

# Forward Propagation

z1 = tf.matmul(X, W1) + b1
a1 = tf.sigmoid(z1)

z2 = tf.matmul(a1, W2) + b2
a2 = tf.sigmoid(z2)

h = a2

ce_cost = - tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(h) + (1 - y) * tf.log(1 - h), 1))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.argmax(h, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1)), tf.float32))

# Intermediate

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(ALPHA)
train = optimizer.minimize(ce_cost)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

for i in range(ITERATIONS):

  random_shuffling = np.arange(m)
  np.random.shuffle(random_shuffling)

  x_train = x_train[random_shuffling]
  y_train = y_train[random_shuffling]

  x_batches = [x_train[j : j + BATCH_SIZE] for j in range(0, m, BATCH_SIZE)]
  y_batches = [y_train[j : j + BATCH_SIZE] for j in range(0, m, BATCH_SIZE)]

  for x_batch, y_batch in zip(x_batches, y_batches):

    sess.run(train, {X : x_batch, y : y_batch})

  print(i, ": ", sess.run(accuracy, {X : x_test, y : y_test}))
```

Output :

- 0 :  0.9399
- 1 :  0.9456
- 2 :  0.951
- 3 :  0.9517
- 4 :  0.9534
- 5 :  0.9566
- 6 :  0.9526
- 7 :  0.098
- 8 :  0.098
- ...
- 29 :  0.098

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess you need to decay your learning rate over time, or my preferred approach, use an optimizer with an adaptive learning rate. Try changing your optimizer to:

```py
optimizer = tf.learn.AdamOptimizer()  # default parameters are probably fine
```

and see if that helps.

If you would rather manually decay your learning rate, you can do that by creating a placeholder for the learning rate and then feeding the rate into your graph at each training step. Something like:

```py
lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='learning_rate')
optimizer = tf.learn.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr)

# ... other definitions ...

# Training process
for i in range(iterations):
    lr = # some decaying function of i
    # ... other stuff ...
    sess.run(train, {X:x_batch, y:y_batch, lr:lr})
```

Comment: I tried the Adam Optimizer, I'm still getting the same issue if I increase my number of hidden units.

Changing the learning rate is not going to do anything, the problem is not that it is stagnating, it is that it straight up just stops working and makes random prediction (which is why there is a ~10% accuracy rate (10 different labels))

Comment: Try the learning rate. It could just be that the rate is too high as it starts to settle in to something, so it jumps out of whatever minima it has found and then can't find its way back to a reasonable minima.

Comment: As the Open AI researcher commented, it seems that this "breaking" thing I noticed is actually a common thing. So it is indeed the learning rate that is causing the issue. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: @AlphaCentauri so just to be clear, this was correct, but the Open AI guy gets it for posting "stay calm" picture and being from Open AI? Got it.

Comment: No, he explained the reason behind it, SGD is unstable and maximizes the loss rather than minimize it at a certain point.

Your proposition to lower the learning rate was indeed correct but you didn't give me a reason why, or rather gave me the wrong reason.

I am still trying to understand what causes maximising effect, but haven't found success yet.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common scenario when training with SGD-type algorithms. Things go swimmingly until everything just "breaks". Symptoms are a drop in accuracy or NaN's or numerical overflow. The underlying reason is that SGD-type algorithms are unstable and can sometimes become loss maximizing rather than loss minimizing. The "D" in "SGD" is a misnomer unless you are doing something smart with adaptive step size.

Almost universal solution to lower the learning rate. We had this picture in Google Brain office.

[image]

Comment: Oh my ... I didn't know. I thought that keeping a steady learning rate would simply make the algorithm stagger around a certain point, but not actually break anything.

Thank you very much.